# Sharepoint wsp deployment why is setup.bat 100 times slower than Visual Studio deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, deployment, wsp

When right-clicking in Solution Explorer and deploy - it takes seconds.

When running `setup /uninstall http://site` from the `\bin` folder of the solution, it takes 13 minutes?! There are 8 features to activate, but my question is why does it take so long; and what is the equivalent command to deploy it the way Visual Studio [2005] does to Sharepoint [2007]?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's so slow. However, speaking about VSeWSS, the `bat`-way is implemented in a different way than how the integration within VS works.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to deploy using whatever way VS does? Does it skip the deactivate/retract/delete - add/activate cycle?

Comment: No, it uses this cycle. VSeWSS calls SharePoint APIs directly — AFAIK. Use Reflector to find out precisely.

Answer (score 2):

When VS deploys a WSP it does so using the equivalent of the -local switch.  This flag allows a synchronous deployment since it only occurs on the server the command is being run from.  Obviously, this is not an option for a multi-server deploy.

If your BAT file is not using this switch then the jobs are being queued to the Timer service for eventual execution.  This may be a part of your issue, although 13 minutes seems too long to be explained by this alone.

Here's one example of an STSADM command that offers the [-local switch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262459%28office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

VS deploys solutions immediately so that you could troubleshoot any problems right away.

You can do that manually for yourself:

Following your setup command, run this:

```
%stsadmpath%\stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
```

Infact this is part of VS deploy commands.

Comment: `Following your setup command` That's the problem, since it would mean "after the 13 minutes", rather than seconds.